# Excel VBA - How to change the width of the "right click on row" popup menu?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written VBA code to add two items to the popup menu that appears when right clicking on a row in Excel:

```
Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Row")

ContextMenu.Width = 400

Dim captionText As String * 45
captionText = "Insert an income, expense or transfer row"

With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!InsertDebitRow"
    .Caption = captionText
    .Tag = "InsertDebitRowContextMenu"
    .Width = 400
End With

captionText = "Insert a beneficiary distribution row"

With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!InsertCreditRow"
    .Caption = captionText
    .Tag = "InsertCreditRowContextMenu"
    .Width = 400
End With
```

The code functions correctly, but the resulting popup menu is not wide enough to accommodate the length of the added msoControlButton captions:

[image]

I have tried various approaches to make the popup menu wider (and they remain in the code I posted).

- I am setting the width of the `ContextMenu` to 400.  This doesn't
  work.
- I am using a fixed length VBA `String` of 45 characters to store
  the caption text and then assign it to the control.  This doesn't
  work.
- I am setting the width of the two added `msoControlButton`s to
  400.  This too doesn't work.

How do I make this popup menu wider?

Comment: You could add a popup control (msoControlPopup) to group your "Insert" options - the sub-menu will be wider

Answer (score 1):

**In Excel97**

Set one of the built in commandbuttons width to the desired value.

```
Application.CommandbarBars("Row").controls(1).Width=400
```

The window will be wide.
The reset give to the same control the default value.

**In Office2010**

After adding the new msocontrolbutton give the desired title to the new button's Caption property. The drop-down
width enlarge to the size of the caption.
[image]

Comment: This had no effect.

Comment: I use it in Excel97 it works. I check it in Office2010 and adding it to my answer

Comment: From your revised answer, I believe I am doing what you suggest: I create the new buttons and set the captions, but the captions are still truncated.  Have you tested your solution in Excel from Microsoft 365 (Excel version 2304)?  If you have, and it works, can you post the change required to the code I supplied in the question?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't access of that version. Is it possible to switch your excel to run in a previous version's mode?

Comment: No, I'm stuck using a more current version.